# Get the string from a cell in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to get the exact string contained within a Google Spreadsheet. I can use getValue or getValues on a range, but this won't return the exact string if Google thinks the value should be another type. For example "99%" will return 0.99 through getValue. I have no way to know if the user entered "0.99" or "99%"

Comment: aren't they the same, except for the format?

Comment: Mathematically, sure. But they're not the same string, and that's what matters. If a user enters 99%, they expect to see 99% come back out, not 0.99.

Comment: yeah so you use getNumberFormat() along with getValue() to make sure what was entered

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues while working on sheets. The solution I have come up with might also work.

Try using these range methods getNumberFormat() and setNumberFormat().

Good luck!